# Use BAT To Start CMD, Load .exe file, and enter a line of text

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, exe

I have a tool to encrypt passwords for an internal application to a value that can be stored in a SQL DB without being easily deciphered.  Traditionally we have had customers adding users to the application one at a time, so they would just add the password when they create the account, but recently have taken on a few projects where there are hundreds of users who need to be imported into the system.  Easiest way to do that is just to import them into the database, but the current scenario requires us to either use the same default password for all users, or manually create a password for each user.  I have PasswordEncrypt.exe which will open a window saying:

```
Enter password to encode:
```

You then type in whatever password you want and it will generate something like:

```
Password(clear):Test
Password(encoded):qw345ua9w45;os580-35i
Press any key to close
```

I'm currently waiting on our developers to update this to allow a mass input of passwords to encrypt, but trying to come up with an alternative in the mean time.  I cannot seem to run this with PowerShell.  If I open PowerShell and run

```
.\PasswordEncrypt.exe
```

I get:

```
Enter password to encode:
```

but it will not allow me to enter any text.  If I do the same thing in CMD, I'm able to run the entire thing in the CMD window without issue.  So I thought maybe I could try to run this with a Bat file.  I've got:

```
Start CMD.exe /k ".\PasswordEncrypt.exe"
```

This will open the CMD window and allow me to manually enter the password, but I'm struggling to figure out if it's even possible to pass along a string of text as the test password and automatically generate it.

My end goal here is to have a CSV with all the information we need to import, use PowerShell to go line by line down the list, call PasswordEncrypt.exe to take the password value from the CSV and encrypt it, then use Invoke-SQLCmd to make the change in the SQL DB using the original CSV and the encrypted password value.  But I'm not quite sure I can make a Bat file do this work for me and am curious if anyone else might know.

Comment: You _MIGHT_ be able to `echo password | PasswordEncrypt.exe`, but honestly, if your program doesn't accept commandline parameters, you're out of luck.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking...  Just figured I'd try to see if there was an alternative

Comment: Actually, that totally works, but it needs to be ```echo password| PasswordEncrypt.exe``` The space between password and | is considered part of the text and ends up with a very different value.  Thank you!